# Sharing views between ASP.NET MVC 3 Web application projects

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have several ASP.NET MVC 3 Web applications that have a lot of common objects:

- The same login controller. The few differences between their login systems are captured in their `web.config` files.
- Header/detail views: invoices, payment orders, payment orders, etc.

In order to make my code less redundant, I moved common controllers and views to a separate class library (models were already in their own class libraries). After googling for a while, I eventually found out [how to call controllers in external assemblies](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/11/14/how-to-call-controllers-in-external-assemblies-in-an-asp.net.aspx), however, I still don't know how to call views in external assemblies. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to look at [MVCContrib Portable areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/). They allow you to compile an entire MVC application area into one assembly, including controllers, views and supporting files such as JavaScript and CSS. I've worked on a large project that made extensive use of them and they work well, especially combined with [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC).